# Taking shell arguments and updating values

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am learning shell scripting and I am wondering how I can take arguments and use them to update a value. For example, I want to accomplish the following:

> Take two arguments. A filename that points to the balance, and a
>   number that indicates the deposit amount. The script should increase
>   the account balance by the deposit amount, and save the result.
>
> Take two arguments. A filename that points to the account balance, and
>   a number that indicates the debit amount. The script should reduce the
>   account balance by the debit amount, and save the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view variables that are handed over to your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "First parameter: $1"
echo "Second parameter: $2"
echo "And so on...."

echo "Number of parameters: $#"
```

So for your exmaple the following code could be possible:

**Increase**: `./inc_script.sh /path/to/file 5`

```
#!/bin/bash

AMOUNT=$(cat $1)

echo $(($AMOUNT + $2)) > $1
```

**Decrease**: `./dec_script.sh /path/to/file 5`

```
#!/bin/bash

AMOUNT=$(cat $1)

echo $(($AMOUNT - $2)) > $1
```

With `$()` you can execute a command in a subshell. With the `$(())` notation you can calculate in bash.